# Cannot obtain values while parallelizing 2 for loops

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run the following snippet which appends data to lists 'tests1' and 'tests2'. But when I print 'tests1' and 'tests2', the displayed list is empty. Anything incorrect here?

```
tests1 = []
tests2 = []

def func1():
    for i in range(25,26):
        tests1.append(test_loader.get_tests(test_prefix=new_paths[i],tags=params.get('tags', None),
                                    exclude=params.get('exclude', False)))

def func2():
    for i in range(26,27):
        tests2.append(test_loader.get_tests(test_prefix=new_paths[i],tags=params.get('tags', None),
                                    exclude=params.get('exclude', False)))


p1 = mp.Process(target=func1)
p2 = mp.Process(target=func2)

p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()

print tests1
print tests2
```

Answer (score 0):

The worker processes don't actually share the same object. It gets copied (pickled).

You can send values between processes using a `multiprocessing.Queue` (or by various other means). See my simple example (in which I've made your tests into integers for simplicity).

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def add_tests1(queue):
    for i in range(10):
        queue.put(i)
    queue.put(None)

def add_tests2(queue):
    for i in range(100,110):
        queue.put(i)
    queue.put(None)

def run_tests(queue):
    while True:
        test = queue.get()
        if test is None:
            break
        print test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue1 = Queue()
    queue2 = Queue()

    add_1 = Process(target = add_tests1, args = (queue1,))
    add_2 = Process(target = add_tests2, args = (queue2,))
    run_1 = Process(target = run_tests, args = (queue1,))
    run_2 = Process(target = run_tests, args = (queue2,))

    add_1.start(); add_2.start(); run_1.start(); run_2.start()
    add_1.join(); add_2.join(); run_1.join(); run_2.join()
```

Note that the parent program can also access the queues.

Comment: Working like this throws this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
    send(obj)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed

Comment: @Aditya It works by pickling and unpickling the objects you add to the queue to send them between processes. Pickle doesn't accept functions. Potentially you could pass back a whole object instead of a method, but without knowing more details of your `test_loader.get_tests` I couldn't say for sure. In my simple example if you wrap the integers in a class and send back a class instance that works, but if you send back an instance method it fails with a similar error as you get.